# In Azure, how do I assign the Regulatory Compliance built-in initiative - ISO 27001:2013 to a Management Group?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to assign the Regulatory Compliance built-in initiative - ISO 27001:2013 to a Management Group? How do I achieve using Terraform?

Comment: I see that you've now asked several questions of a similar style: no code, no programming question, and just "how can I implement..." or "where can I find..." These questions, as well as this one ("How do I achieve...") are all off-topic as written: each one is a high level requirement and then a request for the Community to provide a solution. Just note that recommendation questions are off-topic (e.g. where to find offsite resources), as well as broad or opinion-based questions.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, Thank you for highlighting. All I need some pointers to get started.

Comment: Ok but that's not how Stack Overflow works - you have to ask specific questions, not requests for where to find information. And "pointers to get started"... is equivalent to asking for a custom tutorial, on a broad question. Here, you're asking about Terraform - ok, show the `.tf` you wrote, the specific issue you're having, the expectation vs result, etc. Otherwise, there's just no way to answer such a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could assign the ISO 27001:2013 initiative like mentioned below

```
data azurerm_subscription "current" { }

// ISO 27001:2013 Initivate
data "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "iso27001" {
  display_name = "ISO 27001:2013"
}

resource "azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment" "iso27001_assignment" {
  name                 = "iso27001_assignment"
  policy_definition_id = data.azurerm_policy_set_definition.iso27001.id
  subscription_id      = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  description          = "Assignment of the ISO 27001:2013 initiative to subscription."
  display_name         = "ISO 27001:2013 Governance"
  location             = "eastus"

  identity { 
    type = "SystemAssigned" 
  }
}
```